# How can I capture variable file contents?

Tags: loops, ansible

In my ansible playbook I am taking a variable file as input. A snippet from the ansible-playbook is as follows:

```
  tasks:
    - name: Custom - Only include users in var file specified in usersList param
      include_vars:
        file: vars/users/{{ userVarFile }}
        name: users
      when: Custom
```

The variable file contains the following contents:

```
users_ProjectName:
  - email: john.doe@ibm.com
    firstname: John
    middlename:
    lastname: Doe
    group: advanced
    comment: This is an option comment
```

What I would like to do is loop the file contents but the problem I am hitting is that I have to do something like this:

```
- name: Debug Loop
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ users.users_ProjectName }}"
```

The problem here is that the variable name in the file may change. So what I really want to do is have a way of saying users.[] such that it will take all items from the next level down in the file..

Is there a way I can easily achieve this??
Another option I just thought about - as I could make the variable name the same as the parameter userVarFile I may be able to re-use the userVarFile value in the loop command.

Comment: The other problem I am having is that if I try to use the variable userVarFile it just has a single list of the value of that variable, e.g. users_ProjectName. It doesn't actually retrieve the list by the name of the variable value.
I am trying:
loop: "{{ userVarFile }}"

Answer (score 0):

> So what I really want to do is have a way of saying users.[] such that it will take all items from the next level down in the file..

The thing you are looking for is [dict2items](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#dict-filter), which will decompose your dict into a `list[dict[str,*]]`:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    # just using this as a short example
    var_file_contents:
      users_ProjectName:
      - email: john.doe@ibm.com
        firstname: John
  tasks:
  - debug: var=item
    with_items: >-
      {{ var_file_contents | dict2items | map(attribute='value') | list }}
```

should produce a `list` of all the values under any key in that structure